# Why hasn't this value changed ,use slodity 0.8.6

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I use hardhat test my contract,contract code like this:

```
uint256 public investLength;
    
function A()external{
    uint256 id = investLength++;
    _a(id);
}

function _a(uint256 _Id) internal returns (address) {
   require(_id != 0, 'id zero');
}
```

when running test,return **id zero**.This code doesn't seem to be working =>**investLength++**,this value did not change to 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uint256 id = investLength++;
```

This snippet assigns the current value of `investLength` (which is 0 by default) to `id`, **and then** increments `investLength`.

If you want to increment the `investLength` first, and then assign the already incremented value to `id`, use this expression:

```
uint256 id = ++investLength;
```